# How can I compile TypeScript within a JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a `build.js` file which, as you may have guessed, builds my project. This file aims to:

- Compile `.ts` files and place them into a new directory.
- Create an [asar](https://github.com/electron/asar) containing the compiled files.

Because `typescript` (`tsc`) is [an NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript), I figured I might be able to use it inside of a JavaScript file, in the same way I can use the [`asar` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asar). I was right; I can use the `typescript` package as a regular Node.JS module, however, I do not know how to use it, and ESLint doesn't help me out too much.

Here's my current `build.js`:

```js
const typescript = require("typescript");
```

I cannot find any documentation for this, all I want to do is replicate what `tsc .` would do.

**EDIT:** I do not want to use `child_process`, because it creates new issues, especially when it comes to cross-compatibility and safety.

Comment: "*ESLint doesn't help me out too much.*" - why would it? You want to read the docs of `tsc`, not of `eslint`.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html?

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API for how to use the `typescript` package without the cli. However, this is probably not what you want (which might be the reason why they didn't put it on their normal homepage)

Comment: I was not reading `eslint` docs, I was reading the auto-completions it gave me. I saw `tsc` docs though I did not see the part on integrating it with build tools. This should solve the issue.

Comment: It's not eslint that gives autocompletions, it's the JavaScript (or TypeScript) language server.

Comment: Bergi posted a good link to 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#a-minimal-compiler. You should check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use child process to spawn a shell and run the `tsc` command or use the `exec()` to spawn the shell first then run the command

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-child-process/

You can achieve this with something like

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('tsc', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
console.log(stdout);
  if (stderr!= "")
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

[image]

Comment: The point is that I do not want to use `child_process`, I should have said that in the original post, I guess I forgot.

Comment: May i know why not? It clearly seems to be the best solution

Comment: I edited my post, I want to avoid it because it seems like a shortcut and I don't have 100% faith in it, as it is more likely to fail, for example, when `tsc` in not in `$PATH`.

Comment: `$(which tsc) --init` This is the bash way to do it in case TSC is installed locally

Comment: And that would create issues for Windows users.

Comment: Obviously it would. You should use the compiler API